# Уведомления Firebase In-app Messaging не показываются

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-android

Делал все по документации:

1) Все зависимости подключил

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.1.1'
```

2) В логах вытащил ID тестового устройства:

```
 I/FIAM.Headless: Starting InAppMessaging runtime with Instance ID c0iuht8_M1c
```

3) Создал кампанию в Firebase Console и протестировал на устройстве: ноль реакций. Перезапуск приложения и длительное ожидание ничего не дает.  У индусов же с ютуба на этом этапе уведомление показывалось.

Вместо тестирования пробовал публиковать кампанию, также использовал разные версии в зависимостях - ничего не выходит. В чем проблема, где я мог накосячить? (хотя косячить то особо и негде =) )

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось очень просто. Нужно включить Firebase In-App Messaging API на сайте https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/firebaseinappmessaging.googleapis.com.

Странно, что в документации про это ничего не сказано.